# Enviroment variable for Spyder crashed because of PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, spyder

I have Anacondas distribution with Python 3.7 installed. I usually use Spyder editor, which as far as I know, is based in PyQt library.
As I have to generate a GUI, I installed a tool for PyQt5 so I did:

```
pip install PyQt5
```

and installed that tool. I think something is wrong now with the enviroment variable because Spyder crashes when I start it.

The PATH I have now is:

```
C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\python37
```

which is the path where python.exe is located. Am I doing something wrong or what Am I missing?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Anaconda comes with PyQt5 because Spyder is built on top of it, as you mentioned. So there's no need to additionally install it with pip. By doing so you broke your Anaconda Spyder and your Anaconda installation too, and now you to reinstall it.

Comment: I just tried 2 times, first one adding the path variable in the installation menu and the other one I toogled off that option

Comment: There is no need to add anything to PATH for you to create PyQt5 applications using Spyder and Anaconda. Simply uninstall the PyQt5 you installed with pip, remove Anaconda and reinstall it again for things to work as expected.